# How to write json path expressions for the below script in jmeter . Ineed two dynamic values session id and csrf

Tags: jmeter, correlation, json-path-expression

How to write json path expressions for the below script in jmeter . I need to get the two dynamic values session id and csrf

```
<input type="hidden" name="_txtSession_Id" value="tw-2777518705045647360wor" >         
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="QIuBhc0mxMfA0XMczGIoZ+jPRprc3wfxbxCfjHiAykU=" />
```

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) on HTML data, consider using [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) instead.

The relevant configuration would be something like:

- Name of created variable: anything meaningful, i.e. `_txtSession_Id`
- CSS Selector Expression: `input[name=_txtSession_Id]`
- Attribute: `value`

That's it, you will be able to refer the first value as `${_txtSession_Id}` where required.

The same way you can extract `csrf_token`, just change CSS Selector Expression to `input[name=csrf_token]`

You can test your CSS Expressions using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

[image]